# Selenium returing null values, after second run

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

I have been working on webscraping a sport website data.
When i run the code initialy it does it job correctly, but when i run it again, i get a null result.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.common import TimeoutException
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC


browser = webdriver.Chrome()
browser.get('https://www.skysports.com/premier-league-table')

# Wait
delay = 10 # seconds
try:
    myElem = WebDriverWait(browser, delay).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CLASS_NAME, 'standing-table__cell--name-link')))
    print("Page is ready!")
except TimeoutException:
    print("Loading took too much time!")


body = browser.find_element(By.XPATH, "//table[@class='standing-table__table']/tbody")
items = body.find_elements(By.CLASS_NAME, 'standing-table__row')
for item in items:
    name = item.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, 'standing-table__cell--name-link')
    print(name.text)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You say when you run the code initialy it does it job correctly, but when you run it again,it's null.
And i just ran your code in many times and found it all null,so mabe it's just invalid,we know that reptile have timeliness,you can try to change user-agent or  perform other operations.

Comment: I made use of fake-useragent and also saving and loading of cookies.

Answer (score 0):

If you are running with the intention of reloading the page and checking for changes each time then you should include:

```
browser.quit()
```

At the end of the code and in the exception block.

To close the driver each time and avoid sessions being left open.

Comment: I have this already implemented.